# Keep getting use of undeclared identifier when declared at the start

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak

I'm coding a project using ObjC and currently I'm having trouble getting it to compile properly, due to errors with undeclared identifiers, despite me putting them at the start. I have tried basically everything, from new classes to different variables, some cases got errors with ints, but this was the main issue.

```
@interface MPAVRoute : NSObject
-(NSString *)productIdentifier;
@end

@interface BluetoothDevice : NSObject
-(int *)batteryLevel;
@end

@interface SBVolumeControl : NSObject {
float _GetMediaVolumeForIAP;
}
@end

@interface AVVolumeController : NSObject {
float _volume;
}
@end


%hook MPAVRoutingTableViewCell //calls .h file
- (NSString *)_batteryTextForRoute:(MPAVRoute *)route {
    int volint = (int) _volume
    NSLog(@"%@", [route productIdentifier]);

    if([[route productIdentifier] isEqual: @"BTHeadphones76,8206"]) {
        int hr = (([batteryLevel]/volint)*5)
        double min = (([batteryLevel]%volint)*5)
        NSString *hour = [@(hr) stringValue]
        NSString *mins = [@(min) stringValue]
        NSString *finval = int [batteryLevel]
        NSString *strValues = [finval stringByAppendingString:@"%, "
            hour: stringByAppendingString:@" hours " 
            mins: stringByAppendingString:@" minutes remaining."]
        return strValues;
    }

    return %orig;
}
%end
```

The error that occurs is below.

```
    > Making all for tweak BTTimeRemaining…
==> Preprocessing Tweak.x…
==> Compiling Tweak.x (armv7)…
Tweak.x:22:20: error: use of undeclared identifier '_volume'
int volint = (int) _volume
               ^
Tweak.x:26:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 'batteryLevel'
    int hr = (([batteryLevel]/volint)*5)
            ^
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [/Users/anudeep30/Desktop/bttimeremaining/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/Tweak.x.f89203b0.o] 
Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/anudeep30/Desktop/bttimeremaining/.theos/obj/debug/armv7/BTTimeRemaining.dylib] 
Error 2
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [BTTimeRemaining.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
nbp-51-196:bttimeremaining anudeep30$
```

Comment: You most likely need to be using `self.` or `self->`. Unlike Swift, there is no implied `self` in Objective-C.

Comment: naw the issue was my declaration above. jailbreak obj c is a little different

Comment: you can try add *
 ------->  int *volint = (int) _volume